# Jetty Spnego Authenticator - Any way to log the username?

Tags: jetty, kerberos, audit, spnego

I have an audit requirement to log the requesting username when a client makes requests to my Jetty Spnego Authenticator secured REST end point - is there any built in way of accessing and logging the client principal once authenticated? This is in Jetty 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if memory serves you can get this through the getUserPrincipal() call in the servlet-api